# facility count not using list

Tags: sql, list, count, case

I have a SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  p.id
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN pf.facility_code in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as facility_count
FROM people p
  inner JOIN people_facilities pf ON p.ID = pf.ID
group by p.id
```

and from the above statement, you'd understand that the facility_count can't be greater than 3.  However, the first one in the list has 18 facilities in the count.

I'm referring to [count with case and list](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82487/case-with-multiple-conditions)

Why is this count not working?

Comment: *from the above statement, you'd understand that the facility_count can't be greater than 3* it could be greater than 3 if for an id there may exist more than 1 rows for each of 'S','H','E'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of *different* facilities, use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT p.id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pf.facility_code in ('S','H','E') THEN pf.facility_code END) as facility_count
FROM people p JOIN
     people_facilities pf
     ON p.ID = pf.ID
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Your query is suspicious.  I would expect the `JOIN` to be more like `pf.PeopleID = p.id`.

If not, this query can be simplified by removing the `JOIN`, because the `ID` you are aggregating by is in the `people_facilities` table.  I also suspect the condition can be moved to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT pf.id, COUNT(DISTINCT pf.facility_code) as facility_count
FROM people_facilities pf
WHERE pf.facility_code IN ('S', 'H', 'E')
GROUP BY pf.id;
```

Comment: I tried just using the where clause and it was returning 18 for the first facility count still.

Answer (score 1):

After the join, there may exist multiple rows with the same `id` and the same `facility_code`. 
So first get distinct pairs of these columns and then group and aggregate:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.facility_code in ('S','H','E') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as facility_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT p.id, pf.facility_code
  FROM people p inner JOIN people_facilities pf 
  ON p.ID = pf.ID
) t
group by t.id
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me, but I'm using the other answer. Thanks!